# How to query ONLY 2nd level categories?

Tags: php, mysql

this is my code, it displays all the categories like

> A
>   -A.1
>   -A.2
>     B
>   -B.1
>   -B.2
>
> And now i want it displays only
>
> > A.1
> >         A.2
> >         B.1
> >         B.2

Any idea?

```
    function current_categories($m,$id){
    $cat_array=array();
    $sql = "select * from `category`";
    $query = DB::Query($sql);
        while($row = DB::fetch_array($query)){
            $cat_array[] = array($row['id'],$row['name'],$row['classid'],$row['sort']);
        } 
        if($id==""){
            $id=0;
        }
    $n = str_pad('',$m,'-',STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $n = str_replace("-","&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",$n);
    for($i=0;$i<count($cat_array);$i++){
        if($cat_array[$i][2]==$id){
        echo "<li>"."<a href=\"/team/index.php?gid=".$cat_array[$i][0]."\">".$cat_array[$i][1]."</a></li>"; 
    current_categories($m+2,$cat_array[$i][0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is you category table structure?

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is a recursive function that calls `select * from category` numerous times just to show a hierarchical list of categories?

Comment: **What** are you doing?? You're converting a perfectly good associative array into a numerically indexed array ($row)

Comment: @ypercube: Correct, because he has not found a way to to get the rows into the correct order before outputting them.

Comment: For every row in your `category` table, the fuction calls again `select * from category` and loops through all results to find those rows which are one level down and "under" the first one? I would like to see the performance of this code with 10K+ rows in the table.

Comment: I know this kind of queries are quite hard to do in MySQL but when one doesn't know how to do that in SQL, a more clever approach would be to get the data with **one** `SELECT` call and loop recursively through the result set.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what value you put in as classid for the toplevel classid values. NULL or -1 perhaps?

```
function second_level_categories(){
    $sql = " SELECT lvl2.* FROM `category` as lvl1 "
          ." JOIN `category` as lvl2"
          ."     ON lvl1.id = lvl2.parent_id"
          ." WHERE lvl1.parent_id=VALUE_FOR_TOP_LEVEL"
          ." ORDER BY lvl1.sort ASC, lvl2.sort ASC"

    $result = DB::Query($sql);
    while($category = DB::fetch_array($result)){
        echo '<li><a href="/team/index.php?gid='.$category['id'].'">"';
        echo $category['name'];
        echo '</a></li>';
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help,  the classid is actually parent_id. I typed it wrong